# How to show list of only the completed items?

Tags: flutter

I have a button and every time I press it should either show me the completed or uncompleted.

I tried to think of how everything should work. But can't figure out how to sort them properly, loop through all or loop through all completed.

```dart
tasks.forEach((task) {
      if (task.completed) {
        list.removeAt(task);
      } else {
        list.insert(tasks.indexOf(task), task);
      }
    });
```

The first press should show the completed only and next press only the uncompleted and it keeps going on like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`where`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) to filter out items from the list:

```dart
List completed = tasks.where( (task) => task.completed).toList();
```